# Viewing Slack compliance archives

Tags: node.js, postgresql, slack

I need some assistance viewing and searching slack archives. I have a zip file of my archives I'm trying to pass (see details below).

I found this project and cloned it. 
https://github.com/dting/slack-archive-viewer.

I installed node and postgres. 
I created an .env file in folder slack-archive-viewer: with the following details:

```
APP_SECRET= APP_SECRET   ( I set this = to Client Secret listed in slack - to connect to the slack API)
SLACK_ID =SLACK_ID       ( I set this to the slack Client ID without quotes)
SLACK_SECRET= SLACK_SECRET (i set this to the slack  Verification Token )
DOMAIN = http://localhost:9000
```

Are these settings correct or do I need to use other settings, where would I find the correct settings in slack?

I then tried following this step:

`npm run parse -- -f -file=export.zip -team=myteam`

But I get the following errors (specifically ran: `npm run parse -- -f -file=test.zip -team="my team name"`)

The specific errors I am getting are:

```
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm v3.10.10
npm ERRR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! slarchuvuerer@1.0.0 parse: 'rimraf tmp && node -r dotenv/config 
export-parser/index.js "-f" "file" "=test.zip" "-team=my team name"'
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the slarchiviewer@1.0.0 parse script 'rimraf tmp &&node -
r dotenv/config export-parser/index.js "-f" "file" "=test.zip" "-team=my 
team name"'.
npm ERR! make sure you have the latest version of node,js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the slarchiviewer 
package, not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! rimraf tmp && node -r dotenv/config export-parser/index.js "-f" "-
file" "=test.zip" "team =my team name"
```

...

Can you suggest what I can do to correct these errors and get this working?
The error says I need the latest version of node which I believe is 8, but the requirements for this project say node 6.

Has anyone successfully  installed and run this, and can provide instructions for configuring and running?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I've just edited your post (it still needs to be accepted), to make it clearer. In the future, if you want to make it more likely to get an answer, try to format your post to the best of your abilities. It was extremely hard to read.

Comment: Thanks Jeff I accepted your edit.